# Retrieve last version in many-to-many association with junction table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have three models, Task, Milestone and Detail.
In order to log the history of a task, a new detail-record is created in a junction (join) table every time the task or milestone changes.

My problem is to create a chainable query that retrieves the most updated information about every task. Using .group has worked for a while:

```
  @most_recent_details = Detail.order("updated_at DESC").group(:task_id)
```

But when I try to further filter that collection, e.g. verifying a certain milestone's presence, the above sorting is ignored and returns older records that aren't included in collection:

```
  @most_recent_details.where(milestone_id: 2)
```

---

Task
has_many :details

Milestone
has_many :details

Detail
belongs_to :task
belongs_to :milestone
attr_accessible :task_title, :task_id, :milestone_id

### UPDATE

Trying to clarify the issue even more, this is what I want the application to accomplish in a effective manner:

Find every TASK for every MILESTONE, IF that task's corresponding most recent DETAIL doesn't say that there isn't any assigned milestone.

Comment: seems like using `has_many through:` would be a good fit here. Tell me if you need more information about it

Comment: Yes, :through could possibly be of help. But it's only a step in the right direction. Have updated the issue.